# What is the best way to send Django 500 error email on Google App Engine?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm using the latest tools provided by the latest Google App Engine (GAE) environment, i.e. Django 1.3 via

```
libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.3"
```

as instructed by the GAE docs here.

Still, although I found a lot of links discussing how to send the blessed HTTP500 email using the powerful GAE-Django combo, all of them are outdated because they are either simply too old or use "additional" tools like AppEngineHelper or django-nonrel.

Back to my problem: I set up my `settings.py` to follow the Django docs instructions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#server-errors), and since on GAE [opening sockets is restricted](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Sandbox) I end up with this traceback:

```
ERROR    2012-03-21 23:11:15,855 base.py:209] Internal Server Error: /contact/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/josvic/dev-tools/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/josvic/dev/qdsa/gae/apputil/decorators.py", line 14, in wrapper
    output = func(request, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/josvic/dev/qdsa/gae/qdcom/views/contact.py", line 26, in __call__
    return self.f(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/josvic/dev/qdsa/gae/qdcom/views/contact.py", line 59, in contact_page
    msg.send()
  File "/home/josvic/dev-tools/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3/django/core/mail/message.py", line 251, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/josvic/dev-tools/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 79, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/home/josvic/dev-tools/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 42, in open
    local_hostname=DNS_NAME.get_fqdn())
  File "/home/josvic/dev-tools/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3/django/core/mail/utils.py", line 16, in get_fqdn
    self._fqdn = socket.getfqdn()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getfqdn'
```

So that is the problem. Do we have a standard way of circumventing this?

The only thing I can think of to bypass this problem is to resort to a custom `500error` handler that uses GAE's standard mail API.

Comment: How is django-nonrel "decaying"? It is a fully maintained project, with owners and contributors. What can you mean?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hi Daniel. Thank you for your comment. I replaced the "decaying" with "additional". You're right. I meant "decaying" in the sense that with the Python2.7 environment and CloudSQL you simply don't need django-nonrel to run traditional Django apps, i.e.  I meant more of a "decaying" use case than a decaying tool since now you can have a relational DB backend on GAE. django-nonrel is meant for use with an noSQL db, not just with GAE; you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options I can think of are:

1. Custom logging handler that uses GAE standard mail API, not too different from a 500 error handler, but you don't have to rewrite the view:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/
2. Replace the email backend.  I'm not 100% certain this works, but I suspect it will.  There's already one in the Django-nonrel project (which incidentally, is still maintained)
   https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine
   look in mail.py

Comment: I've gone for option 1! Option 2 didn't work out, as I ended up with the original issue. I did an app with specific GAE stuff, so it's easy to fall back to the default Django handler in case I decide to switch to some other provider instead of AppEngine.

Comment: Here's another email backend for option 2, reportedly this one works.  http://andialbrecht.de/blog/2009/11/04/pluggable-app-engine-e-mail-backends-for-django.html